# Missing folders make my Windows 10 system hang

Tags: windows, windows-10, nas

I have been recently facing some issues with my local Terramaster NAS and after a long struggle I ended up buying a Synology NAS as a replacement.

I used the NAS for sharing files in my home network between some PCs, Macs and Android devices.

After the old NAS stopped working I have been facing a number of issues while normally browsing folders or using software on my Windows 10 PC. Basically any time I end up clicking in the File Explorer on a missing folder the software or file explorer just hangs and becomes unresponsive for a while.

My conclusion (obviusly I might be wrong) is that the system tries to search in its local network resources for the missing folders but cannot complete the task and so hangs on it for a while.

Other software, where shortcuts were saved for folders placed on the NAS and are now missing, is facing similar problems. One is music software Ableton Live that became so unresponsive after even just trying to execure a "open file" command that I had to resets its preference file (I guess because it was searching for now inexistent folders where previous projects were stored).

How can I solve this kind of problems? Specifically for Windows is there an option in the registry or in file explorer to just stop this behaviour?

It is something I guess could be pretty common. I faced it myself in the past many times (any time an existing folder on the local network went missing for a number of reasons) and I find it pretty annoying.

Am I missing some basic fature of the system that would help me face this kind of annoyances?

Comment: This behavior is not normal.  I would start by [looking at the shell extensions](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) that have been added to the windows explorer.  One of them is probably the culprit.

Comment: In addition to checking shell extensions, I would recommend checking that all paths found under `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders` are still valid. Then perhaps, perform a search in `regedit.exe` for the names of NAS folders that no longer exist.

Comment: Thank you for the hints. I was able to evolve the situation by installing SheelExView and WhatIsHang from Nirsoft website. Now, while these software are in action, commands related to hanging folder crash abruptly but after executing the given command: I guess it is a step forward!